# 535330#535330: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: django, linux, nginx, ssl, websocket

I have made a django chatting application that uses websockets (django-channels) to implement its chatting functionality. I have used nginx and gunicorn for production for this website.
The following is the nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.aniconnect.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.aniconnect.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.aniconnect.org/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/gamedeveloper/anime_chat/anime_chat_app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The following are the ports I use on this site:

```
gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The following is settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY ='django-insecure-00ejr3$lw40)nu8ojp70w29ju(c+jgol94_m3-otie-csmt^@t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.ip.address', 'www.aniconnect.org']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    'common_anime_chat.apps.CommonAnimeChatConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'anime.apps.AnimeConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'anime_chat_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'anime_chat_app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
        'default':{
    'database':'info'
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    }
]

LOGGING_CONFIG = None

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

import os

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
#CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'common-anime-chat-home'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'anime_chat_app.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}
```

The following is the whole error I am getting:

```
gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2023/10/02 09:13:17 [error] 510942#510942: *1170 open() "/home/gamedeveloper/anime_chat/anime_chat_app/static/admin/javascript/hetong.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: some.ip.address, server: my.ip.address, request: "GET /static/admin/javascript/hetong.js HTTP/1.1", host: "my.ip.address"
2023/10/02 13:40:22 [notice] 533924#533924: signal process started
2023/10/02 13:40:25 [notice] 533926#533926: signal process started
2023/10/02 13:40:28 [notice] 533928#533928: signal process started
2023/10/02 13:40:29 [notice] 533930#533930: signal process started
2023/10/02 13:42:10 [notice] 533978#533978: signal process started
2023/10/02 13:42:13 [notice] 533980#533980: signal process started
2023/10/02 15:38:16 [crit] 533981#533981: *98 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: some.ip.address, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/10/02 15:43:55 [crit] 533981#533981: *108 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: some.ip.address, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/10/02 16:20:07 [crit] 533981#533981: *125 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: some.ip.address, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2023/10/02 16:48:08 [warn] 535207#535207: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:48:08 [notice] 535207#535207: signal process started
2023/10/02 16:48:11 [warn] 535213#535213: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:48:11 [notice] 535213#535213: signal process started
2023/10/02 16:49:20 [warn] 535224#535224: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:49:20 [notice] 535224#535224: signal process started
2023/10/02 16:49:42 [warn] 535232#535232: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:49:42 [notice] 535232#535232: signal process started
2023/10/02 16:53:10 [warn] 535281#535281: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:55:55 [warn] 535317#535317: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:55:55 [notice] 535317#535317: signal process started
2023/10/02 16:56:48 [warn] 535330#535330: conflicting server name "www.aniconnect.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/10/02 16:56:48 [notice] 535330#535330: signal process started
2023/10/02 17:00:17 [notice] 535375#535375: signal process started
```

There don't seem to be any syntax errors in my nginx configuration:

```
gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

So here is what happened: The website was working fine when it just had an IP address, but then I wanted it to get SSL encryption so that it was secure so I followed the docs of
LetsEncrypt at https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal
I reached the step where I had to enter "sudo certbot --nginx" in my ubuntu terminal. I did that and found out that I needed a domain name to do that.
I tested my website and the chatting functionality of the site had suddenly broken (which I thought was part of the process) so I bought a domain name on namecheap.
I then got my site SSL encrypted and it went on smoothly
Then I followed the steps in the linode docs at https://www.linode.com/docs/products/networking/dns-manager/get-started/ to move forward with my project.
I followed the steps properly without any problems until the link to my site started returning a "Site can't be reached error". I went online to do some debugging and the info
I mentioned above is all that I could find to.

Also, every time I mention "my.ip.address" in the post, I am referring to the IP address of my website and the JS file not found error that I am getting in the error log, I have no clue how that got there as I did not write any programs that created that file or created that file myself. I didn't even know something like that existed until it popped up. Is it unrelated to the main error or is it a byproduct of that error itself?

Please help me out.

Comment: Off-topic here, on-topic at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. It should be obvious where the `server` block with the duplicated `server_name` comes from. Maybe your editor has left a backup file.